# MASM compare uninitialized buffers

Tags: assembly, masm, buffer

I'm stuck writing my program
Here's what I wanted it to do:

1. display a welcome message inside a console
2. Wait for the user to imput a number from 0 to 9]
3. compare that number to 0
4. display a message if it is, else exit

Here is what I currently have:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

.data
capt db "SCHiM says: ",0
txt       db "Enter a number 0-9:",0

.data?

data db ?

.code

start:


call AllocConsole

push offset txt
call StdOut

push 1
push offset data
call StdIn

mov al, data

cmp al, 0h
jz eqzero

invoke ExitProcess, NULL

eqzero:

push offset capt
call StdOut
push offset data
call StdOut

endloop:
jmp endloop

invoke ExitProcess, NULL
end start
```

The program assembles & links perfectly without any warnings or errors
But cmp always returns 1, if I print the value in data (with StdOut) it shows me the exact value I've put in. So why isn't it working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are StdIn and StdOut? Are they macros or functions from MASM distribution? I don't have any modern MASM distribution handy to check.

Comment: I would suggest using NASM, it has a much clearer sintax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmp al, '0'
```

-or-

```
cmp al, 48
```

Why? Because you are interested in character '0', not numeric 0. Character '0' is encoded as 48 in most encodings.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably moving the **address** of *data* to al somehow. Try
 `mov al, [data]`
to get the value stored at *data*.

Comment: Your solution has no effect, my program still doesn't take the jump
I've also run it though ollydbg (a debugger)
I see this line, somehow the value stored in al is 01 instead of 00


0040101B  |. A0 30304000    MOV AL,BYTE PTR DS:[403030]

ps: I'm sorry for the horrible format of my posts, I'm not used to the way stackoverflow wraps it's text